# Common cases in which all sessions are thrown

Tags: asp.net

I have a website where the id of the users saved in session object
And any action that the user does, the session is tested to see whether or not it null
Sometimes an Exception occurs in one of the users actions and then all sessions thrown out
What makes all users thrown out to login page, and this very serious problem.
I must find the cases where failure throws all sessions
I have a sample error that happened to me, Not sure if these cases are the reason:
For example:

1. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2. This is an invalid script resource request.
   at System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.Throw404()
3. This is an invalid webresource request.
   at System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessReques
   (HttpContext   context)
4. Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted 
   127.0.0.1:3306
5. Invalid viewstate. Client IP: 77.127.17.24

In short, what should I do?
Where to start looking?
Thanks
Micha

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, this may prove useful: [Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604).

Answer (score 0):

set a global error handler in global.asax to handle these errors gracefully.
and, of course- check for the origins of those errors using the stack trace provided, to avoid them altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your app pool is recycling.

If session is configured to be in process and your app pool recycles, then you will lose all of your session information.  Judging by your other questions, it sounds like this is highly likely.

The first thing I would do is move session to be out of process with sql server as the backing store.  This way they will survive an app pool recycle and mitigate the issue.

Next you will want to figure out why the app pool is recycling.  App pools are generally configured to recycle under certain conditions such as high memory usage or code deployment.  Profile the application to see if you aren't properly disposing of objects; DB connections being a primary one.  There are other triggers to recycling such as on a scheduled basis, etc.

If for some reason this is occuring due to code deployments, then I'd recommend you set scheduled maintenance periods on when new code drops should occur.

Comment: One thing that caused our app pool to recycle was our file upload process.  It would create a folder for a user and put their uploaded files in that folder.  If the folder is created underneath the root of your web application, it will cause the app pool to recycle cuz it treats new folders as "code deployment"